# NVML Drivers Mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

NVML  Driver/library version mismatch

we have nvidia-415, nvidia-390, nvidia-396, nvidia-418, nvidia-384, nvidia-410, nvidia-430 drivers.

lsmod | grep nvidia

nvidia_uvm 663552 0
nvidia_drm 49152 1
nvidia_modeset 860160 4 nvidia_drm
nvidia 13164544 191 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
drm_kms_helper 126976 1 nvidia_drm
drm 344064 4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

Comment: i have nvidia quadro p1000 graphics card installed

Comment: Whats the question here?